# Would we see any speedup using ZeroMQ  instead of TCP Sockets if the two processes communicating are on the same machine?

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I understand that 0MQ is supposed to be faster than TCP Sockets in a clustered environment and I can see where that would be the case (I think that's what they're referring to when they say "Faster than TCP, for clustered products and supercomputing" on the 0MQ website).  However, will I see any kind of speedup using 0MQ instead of TCP sockets to communicate between two processes running on the same machine?

Comment: You have chosen the answer to try UPDA multicast, have you tried? Was it improving the situation, any expirience feedback?

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is correct.  The question then becomes can ZMQ UDP be faster than standard C lib UDP?  I think that the answer is false as ZMQ likely uses the same standard C lib and adds some message headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually running on one machine because the VM is treated as a separate machine. This means that TCP sockets have to run through the whole network stack and cannot take shortcuts like they do when you communicate between processes on one machine.

However, you could try UDP multicast under ZeroMQ to see if that speeds up your application. UDP is less reliable on a wide area network, but in a closed environment of a VM talking to its host, you can safely skip all the TCP reliability stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the short version is give it a try.

The slightly longer version is that writing TCP sockets can be hard, there's a lot of things that are easy to have problems with, but 0MQ guarantees the message will be delivered in its entirety. It is also written by experts in network sockets, which, with the best will in the world, you probably aren't, and they use a few advanced tricks to speed things along.

Answer (score 1):

I guess IPC should be faster than TCP. If you are willing to move to a single process, INPROC is definitely going to be much faster.

Comment: Definitely must have two processes.  One process runs in a VM, the other outside of the VM (but running on the same machine) talks to an external hardware device.  There is some concern right now that the TCP socket for communicating between the VM and the outside process is too slow so just wondering if we can get an improvement using 0MQ.

Comment: it seems you are incorrect. see https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ipc-performance-comparison#:~:text=The%20UNIX%20socket%20transmitted%20at,a%201%20Mbyte%20block%20size.

Answer (score 1):

I think (have not tested) that the answer is false as ZMQ likely uses the same standard C lib and adds some message headers.

Same thing applies for UDP.

Same thing applies for IPC pipes.

ZMQ could be just as fast but since it adds headers it is not likely.

Now it could be a different story if you really need some sort of header and ZMQ has implemented it better than you. Like for message size or type, but I digress.